# Oracle rounding digits after comma

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

I would like to round numbers in Oracle to keep only 2 digits after comma following the value of the third decimal only.
Example of what I would like :

```
1,374 --> 1,37
1,375 --> 1,37 (the 5 need to be rounding down)
1,3756 --> 1,37 (We only look the third decimal, even if the 4th is a 6)
1,376 --> 1,38
```

How would you do that ?
I checked the ROUND() funtion but the behavior is not what I need.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why would you want to round 1,375[999...] *down* to 1.37, but 1.376 *up* to 1.38? That seems like an unusual requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers to both of you guys ! 
It was exactly the kind of trick I was looking for.

    round(trunc(<your number>, 3) - 0.001, 2) --> Works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the value you're rounding slightly, e.g:

```
round(trunc(<your number>, 3) - 0.001, 2)
```

The `trunc(<your number>, 3)` means everything after the third decimal will be ignored, so 1,3756 will be treated the same as 1,375. The `- 0.001` then adjusts that truncated value slightly so that the normal `round()` behaviour will make the tipping point between up and down appear to be at .x6 rather than .x5.

Quick demo:

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters =',.';

with t (n) as (
  select 1.37 from dual
  union all select 1.374 from dual
  union all select 1.374999 from dual
  union all select 1.375 from dual
  union all select 1.375001 from dual
  union all select 1.3756 from dual
  union all select 1.375999 from dual
  union all select 1.376 from dual
  union all select 1.37999 from dual
)
select n, round(n, 2) as simple, trunc(n, 3) as tmp1, trunc(n, 3) - 0.001 as tmp2,
  round(trunc(n, 3) - 0.001, 2) as adjusted
from t;

         N     SIMPLE       TMP1       TMP2   ADJUSTED
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1,37       1,37       1,37      1,369       1,37
     1,374       1,37      1,374      1,373       1,37
  1,374999       1,37      1,374      1,373       1,37
     1,375       1,38      1,375      1,374       1,37
  1,375001       1,38      1,375      1,374       1,37
    1,3756       1,38      1,375      1,374       1,37
  1,375999       1,38      1,375      1,374       1,37
     1,376       1,38      1,376      1,375       1,38
   1,37999       1,38      1,379      1,378       1,38
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `round` combined with `floor` or `trunc` like here:

```
with t as (
  select column_value val 
    from table (sys.odcinumberlist(1.374, 1.375, 1.3756, 1.376)))
select val, 
       round(trunc(val, 3)-.0001, 2) v1, 
       round((floor(val*1000)-1)/1000, 2) v2
  from t
```

Output:

```
       VAL         V1         V2
---------- ---------- ----------
     1,374       1,37       1,37
     1,375       1,37       1,37
    1,3756       1,37       1,37
     1,376       1,38       1,38
```